# SOAP API limit for getUserInfo() method

Tags: api, soap-api, soap

Does SOAP API limit applies for getUserInfo() method ?

```
getUserInfoResult result = connection.getUserInfo();
```

If there is a limit then what will be it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, All SOAP API are subjected to API limits including getUserInfo. The full list of api limits can be found here. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_api.htm

From this big list, as per my understanding, only limit that would be affected by getUserInfo is total number of API calls per 24 hours. Rest all should not be affected.